# Parsing product description from XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a big problem, I don't know how to take product description.
I was doing a lot of different things, but nothing works... I am newbie in XML.

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Product>
    <Criteria>Description</Criteria>
    <Value>
      <![CDATA[
        Refill PLA Pearl White&nbsp;&nbsp;600g<br /> PLA filaments are extracted from biodegradable materials. In addition to being environmentally friendly, it is also suitable for lower temperature printing methods that greatly reduce the warpage along the edges of the printed good. The translucent texture and finishing will also add a unique feature to your finished work.<br /> Filament refills come in small sizes for space-economy and can be used at any given notice, allowing 3D printer operators and hobbyists to do their part for environmental protection while exercising their creative powers.
      ]]>
    </Value>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Criteria>Vendor Homepage</Criteria>
    <Value>eu.xyzprinting.com/eu_en/Product/PLA</Value>
  </Product>
</NewDataSet>
```

My php code :

```
foreach($xml23 as $data3){
    $desc = "Description";
    echo $data3 -> Criteria -> $desc -> Value;
}
```

Comment: You want to get the `<Value>` of `<Product>` which contains `<Criteria>Description</Criteria>`?

Comment: Yeah, exactly this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`xpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to get the value of the `<Value>` tag, which match to `<Criteria>Description</Criteria>`:

```
$xml23->xpath('//Product/Criteria[.="Description"]/../Value');
```

Example:

```
$xml = '<NewDataSet>
<Product>
    <Criteria>Description</Criteria>
    <Value>
    <![CDATA[
    Refill PLA Pearl White&nbsp;&nbsp;600g<br /> PLA filaments are extracted from biodegradable materials. In addition to being environmentally friendly, it is also suitable for lower temperature printing methods that greatly reduce the warpage along the edges of the printed good. The translucent texture and finishing will also add a unique feature to your finished work.<br /> Filament refills come in small sizes for space-economy and can be used at any given notice, allowing 3D printer operators and hobbyists to do their part for environmental protection while exercising their creative powers.
    ]]>
    </Value>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Criteria>Vendor Homepage</Criteria>
    <Value>eu.xyzprinting.com/eu_en/Product/PLA</Value>
</Product>
</NewDataSet>';

$xml23 = simplexml_load_string($xml, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$elm = $xml23->xpath('//Product/Criteria[.="Description"]/../Value');
echo (string)$elm[0];
```

Output:

> Refill PLA Pearl White  600g<br />- PLA filaments are extracted...

Comment: Works perfect!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Should you wish to load the given XML from a file (text.xml) and loop all Product children, you could use the following:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml', "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);

foreach($xml->Product as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value->Criteria;
    echo $value->Value;
}
```